# Unable to get "inbetween" records if year is different

Tags: php, mysql

I am having this unique bug

```
TABLE : tbl
id | title | iscancel | sold_dt

id: UID
Title : varchar
iscancel : 0/1
sold_dt : timestamp


select * from tbl where iscancel = 0 and DATE_FORMAT(sold_dt,"%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN "06/01/2015" AND "03/01/2016" GROUP BY day(sold_dt) order by (sold_dt) asc
```

(note that year is different)

- 0 records returned

but if i do

```
select * from tbl where iscancel = 0 and DATE_FORMAT(sold_dt,"%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN "06/01/2015" AND "12/01/2015" GROUP BY day(sold_dt) order by (sold_dt) asc
```

or

```
select * from tbl where iscancel = 0 and DATE_FORMAT(sold_dt,"%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN "01/01/2016" AND "03/01/2016" GROUP BY day(sold_dt) order by (sold_dt) asc
```

(note that year is same)

-I'll get some records

*Used `DATE_FORMAT` because my calendar is giving me `MM/DD/YYYY` (i can not change since it might affect other areas)

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try by passing static dates into `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Comment: @sandeepsure Yes it is working edit : i tried 2015 - 2016 but only getting 2016 records

Comment: Please provide prepared sql query after inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting the stored value into another format try changing the parameter itself to correct format. If you cant do it on your website you can do it in your query as well

```
sold_dt BETWEEN
STR_TO_DATE('06/01/2015', '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('03/01/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing static dates into DATE_FORMAT() function

```
select * from tbl where iscancel = 0 and DATE_FORMAT(sold_dt,"%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT("06/01/2015","%m/%d/%Y") AND DATE_FORMAT("03/01/2016","%m/%d/%Y") GROUP BY day(sold_dt) order by (sold_dt) asc
```